# Accessing Google API on iOS/Android on a Ionic 4 (Angular & Cordova) app (plus Firebase Authentication)

Tags: angular, cordova, google-api, firebase-authentication, ionic4

does anyone know any example code for what I am asking for?

The best I've got so far is, that I am able to access them, but the user has to login every time for that, as the access_token expires.

So either the access_token (`gplusUser.accessToken`) expires or if I close and reopen the app, the user is still logged in, but I'm not able to access the APIs anymore.

This is how I've achieved my current status:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
    import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus/ngx';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
    import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
    import { firebaseConfig } from '../../../assets/credentials';

    declare var gapi: any;

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-google-login',
      templateUrl: './google-login.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./google-login.component.scss']
    })
    export class GoogleLoginComponent implements OnInit {
      user: Observable<firebase.User>;

      constructor(
        private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
        private gplus: GooglePlus,
        private platform: Platform
      ) {
        this.user = this.afAuth.authState;
        gapi.load('client');
      }

      async nativeGoogleLogin(): Promise<firebase.auth.UserCredential> {
        try {
          const gplusUser = await this.gplus.login({
            webClientId: firebaseConfig.clientId,
            offline: true,
            scopes:
              'profile ' +
              'email ' +
              'https://mail.google.com/ ' +
              'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify ' +
              'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'
          });

          gapi.client.setToken({ access_token: gplusUser.accessToken });

          gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1');

          return await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(
            firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(gplusUser.idToken)
          );
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }

      signOut() {
        this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
        if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
          this.gplus.logout();
        }
      }

      async getGmail() {
        const messages = await gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
          userId: 'me'
        });

        console.log(messages);
      }

      ngOnInit() {}
    }
```